# Converting a Python List into a Numpy Structured array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to convert a Python list with mixed type (integers and floats) to a  Numpy structured array with certain column names.

I have tried the following code but for some reason I cant see it doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
lmtype = [('el','intp',1),  ('n1','intp',1),  ('n2','intp',1),  ('n3','float64',1),
          ('n4','float64',1),  ('n5','float64',1),  ('n6','float64',1),  ('n7','float64',1),
          ('n8','float64',1),  ('n9','float64',1),  ('n10','float64',1),  ('n11','float64',1)]
LAMI = np.zeros(5, dtype=lmtype)
linea = ['1', '2', '3', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
for idx, la in enumerate(LAMI):
    lineanum = ([ int(j) for j in linea[0:3] ] + [float(i) for i in linea[3:12] ] )
    print lineanum
    LAMI[idx] = np.array( lineanum )
```

The code runs, but look what LAMI has inside:

```
>>> LAMI[0]
(0, 1072693248, 0, 5.304989477e-315, 5.307579804e-315, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: `np.array( lineanum )` makes a normal array, and casts the ints of the first three elements into a float to make all the elements the same type. And then the cast to LAMI fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
LAMI[idx] = tuple( lineanum )
```

Tuples are the normal way to assign to a `record` (row) of a structured array. They can hold mixed types, just like the structured element.

`np.array(lineanum)` is all `float`.  `LAMI[idx] = np.array( lineanum )` just copies the buffer full of floats to a segment of the `LAMI` buffer. I'm a little surprised that it permits this copy; it must be doing some sort of 'copy only as much as fits'.  `LAMI.itemsize` is `84`, while the total length of `np.array(lineanum)` is 12*8=96.

```
LAMI[0]=np.array(lineanum, dtype=int) # or better
LAMI[0]=np.array(lineanum[:3], type=int)
```

would also work, since the only nonzero values are those 1st 3 which are suppposed to be ints.

Comment: Great @hpaulj !!! The first solutions works perfectly... Now I see... the structured array is a one dimensional array of tuples, is this ok? Thanks very much for your quick answer!

Comment: Technically it isn't an array of tuples, since the bytes are packed, as opposed to being pointers.  But it is displayed as tuples, and `.tolist()` will produce a list of tuples.  So it is useful to think along those lines.